# How to access a class element which is a List<string> in C#?

Tags: c#, csv

I have a hard time getting the value of an item of a class.
I'm writing a method to reading CSV file. I binding the data which I need into a class. My class looks as follows:

```
public class DatafromCSV
{
    public string ImageId { get; set; }
    public List<string> ImageBbox { get; set; }
    public string Classname { get; set; }

}
```

This is my method to read the CSV file.

```
public static DatafromCSV ReadfromCSV (string path)
    {
        List<string> csvLines = new List<string>();            

        csvLines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
        csvLines = csvLines.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).Distinct().ToList();

        DatafromCSV currentRecord = new DatafromCSV();
        foreach (string line in csvLines)
        {
            string[] items = line.Split(',', '.');               

            currentRecord.ImageId = items[0];
            currentRecord.ImageBbox = new List<string>() { items[2], items[3], items[4], items[5] };
            currentRecord.Classname = items[6];

        }

        return currentRecord;
    }
```

I initialize my method as follows:

```
var infoCSV = ReadfromCSV(path);
```

After initializing the function I can access the ImageId and Classname values:

```
Console.WriteLine(infoCSV.ImageId);
```

However when I try to access the ImageBbox I getting following:

```
Console.WriteLine(infoCSV.ImageBbox);

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

I expecting to get:

```
[2012,1367,2284,1473]
```

Is there a problem with how I calling it or in general in my approach? I have tried what I can but without any success. How can I get what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1) to print list to the console.

```
Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", infoCSV.ImageBbox)}]");
```

---

[From MSDN: string.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1)

> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a
>   collection, using the specified separator between each element or
>   member.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` doesn't implement a custom `ToString` method override. So you get the default one, which gives you the type.

If you want to print out the elements in a list, it's as easy as using `string.Join`:

```
Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(",", infoCSV.ImageBbox)}]");
```